# Change measurement unit of Ruler in NSScrollview

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, interface-builder

Im trying to make a drawing application. So i have a subclass of NSScrollView that i use to show the rulers.

```
[self setHasHorizontalRuler: true];
[self setHasVerticalRuler:YES];
[self setRulersVisible:true];
[self setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
```

The problem is that the numbers of the ruler have different units that the ones i use to draw. Here the points i wanted to draw are (0,0) (22,12) and (5,7)

[image]

I know theres a register measurement unit and a set for NSRulerView and some default units, but i can't find what are the default ones, or any example of how can i use it in an NSScrollView class. Should i just multiply every coordinate for a constant? In that case what constant is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default units are listed in the description of the `registerUnitWithName:abbreviation:unitToPointsConversionFactor:stepUpCycle:stepDownCycle:` class method, and the current ruler unit can be found from the property `measurementUnits`.

The description tells you the Points/Unit for each pre-defined Unit Name. The measurement unit of your drawing view is points, so to draw in ruler units take your location and multiply each coordinate by the Points/Unit for the `measurementUnits` of the appropriate ruler (horizontal/vertical). E.g. consider your location`(5, 7)` with the ruler units set to Centimeters then the Points/Unit are 28.35 and your location is `(141.75, 198.44)` in points.

HTH